# What do you think about a Stack Exchange forum about CS and coding, but for newbie or intermediate level questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Exactly like MathOverflow vs. Mathematics?

Comment: I repeat: **We are not a forum**.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Would you recommend Stack Exchange sites vs. other types of fora?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rough equivalent to MathOverflow would be [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour).

The equivalent to Mathematics would be either [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and/or [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). I agree that this isn't totally obvious upon visiting CSTheory; maybe we should do more to promote Stack Overflow?

wait... how did you get here?

Comment: _wait... How did you get here?_ already 40M page views PM and already popular one. still you want to promote it?

Answer (score 6):

> but for newbie or intermediate level questions?

What makes you think those aren't welcome on Stack Overflow?

The site is full of questions that can be solved with a bit of searching and/or debugging, and new ones arrive every second.

What the average asker lacks is knowledge of how to break up a problem into smaller parts they can solve on their own, the ability to describe what problem they actually have (either to other people or to a web search engine) and experience using a debugger.

They also don't know how to recognize where they are in solving a problem: did they almost solve the entire problem but need help with the last bit, did they go wrong from the start, or are they asking a question about an XY problem?

What the site lacks on the other hand is people with enough time, patience and experience to explain to all of those people what they're doing wrong and teach them how they can solve the next problem.

Instead we just have a horde of answerers who Google the question title and dump a copypaste of the first hit, or they share their favorite snippet from their voodoo library. Some even do it by memory, but those should know better and use the duplicate close vote more often.

Anyway, what you're asking for already exists: it's Stack Overflow itself. Just make sure you thoroughly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and spend some effort creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I disagree with you.  First, newbies might be welcome on Stack Overflow, but their questions usually aren't.  Asking basic questions without code is verboten, and questions like "Where can I find a library that does [xyz]" are closed as "off-topic".  Even the way you post your code can be reason to be harangued (politely, of course).  No, a "Newby Coder" or somesuch would be a double blessing:  It would remove the "off-topic" questions from the community that the experienced users frequent, and give beginner programmers a chance to get their questions answered.

Comment: @Bob ansered by whom though?

Comment: Well, I would, for one.  I don't have an encyclopedic knowledge of programming, but I could probably teach a basic programming course.  Plus, a lot of people on here are teachers at heart -- at least, that's the impression I get in reading some of the answers.  People aren't limited to just one community.